# getAssets() not showing up while defining createFromAsset (for a different class other than MainActivitiy.class)

Tags: java, android

[image]I'm not able to put the custom font through Typeface, as getAssets() is not showing up while writing createFromAsset. 
I've don't know the exact syntax. It's asking for context. Help me out with the code.
Please tell me the error.

```
package com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.ViewHolder;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.shubhojit.careersafter10th.R;

public class Courses_After10thViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView txtCourseName;
    public ImageView courseImage;
    public TextView txtCourseDuration;
    Typeface courseName;
    Typeface courseDuration;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public Courses_After10thViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtCourseName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_name);
        courseImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_image);
        txtCourseDuration = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_duration);

        courseName = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf");

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use your `View` 's `Context` like this: getContext().getAssets()

Comment: simply writing getContext() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `context` for this

```
public Courses_After10thViewHolder(View itemView, Context mContext) {
        super(itemView);

        txtCourseName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_name);
        courseImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_image);
        txtCourseDuration = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.courses_after10th_duration);

        courseName = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(),"Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf");

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

If you now want to pass `context` you can use `itemView.getContext()` instead as follows :

```
courseName = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(),"Fonts/Antipasto-RegularTrial.ttf");
```

Comment: If it's working feel free to mark my answer as a correct and upvote it please, thanks! :D